# How to make Double number to add thousand mark and set minimumFractionDigits?

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I have a question about number formatter.
I want to add thousand separator mark to my double number.
And I also to set it's minimumFractionDigits, but I failed.

```
func formatterNumberToString(_ numberText: String, digits: Int) -> String {

    let str = numberText
    let formatter = Formatter.withSeparator
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = digits

    let finalStr = formatter.string(for: Double(str)!)

    if let finalStr = finalStr {
        return finalStr
    } else {
        return "none"
    }
}

self.formatterNumberToString("10003232.234", digits: 2) //it return 10,003,232.234
```

Why minimumFractionDigits not work?

Comment: Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine. The condition for minimum number of digits is met. What you probably need is to always show 2 digits. So, just add this line,

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = digits
```

This will display

> 10,003,232.23